# logcat text colour: what do the different colours represent?

Tags: android, eclipse

In my (Eclipse) logcat window, some text is written in blue, others in green and orange colours. i know when the text is red, there is an error in my app that i need to fix. What do the other text colours represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Logcat colors represent the **importance** of the color, determined by the Log command, which was used. You can check the **level** (as the importance is called in logcat) of the message in the first row of the logcat table.

e.g.:

- red is for errors, caused by Log.e(...)
- blue is for debug messages, caused by Log.d(...)
- green is for info messages, caused by Log.i(...)
- ...

All possible message types and an good explanation are shown at the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Answer (score 0):

The filter buttons on the LogCat pane in Eclipse are colour-coded to match the colour of the messages, so:

Verbose - black

Debug - blue

Info - green

Warning - orange

Error - red

Answer (score 0):

Verbose - black, Debug - blue, Info - green, Warning - orange, Error - red

For more information read [description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)